# Suppress Selenium Warnings when running Cucumber Test on Local Machine

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver, capybara

I am trying to suppress **selenium** warning whenever I run a cucumber test on my local machine.

I tried the following:

1. `options.add_argument("--disable-logging")`
2. `options.add_argument('log-level=3')`

Below is what the warnings look like on my console:

```
2019-04-23 12:42:33 WARN Selenium [DEPRECATION] Selenium::WebDriver::Error::InvalidElementStateError is deprecated. Use Selenium::WebDriver::Error::ElementNotInteractableError (ensure the driver supports W3C WebDriver specification) instead.
2019-04-23 12:42:33 WARN Selenium [DEPRECATION] Selenium::WebDriver::Error::ElementNotSelectableError is deprecated. Use Selenium::WebDriver::Error::ElementNotInteractableError (ensure the driver supports W3C WebDriver specification) instead.
```

Comment: The problem is not in driver logging (solution You tryied), but in Capybara using old methods on Selenium driver. @Thomas answer should solve it in most cases (unfortunatelly not mine).

Answer (score 6):

Update to the latest Capybara (3.17+) and it should suppress the warnings for you (unless you're actually specifying those classes in your code).  The other option is to lock `selenium-webdriver` to 3.141.0 in your Gemfile.

Comment: Unfortunatelly my system test passing with 3.12 (with warnings) , but not passing with 3.13 (still warnings), so I have to stay on 3.12 (untill I figure out what changes in `assert_no_text`)

Comment: @Foton The answer says to go to 3.17+ - why do you think 3.13 would make a difference?

Comment: I tryied 3.34. No warings, but failing test. Then I pin down that 3.13 is first version which broke will not let my test pass. Sorry for misleading. I was meant as side note about upgrading.